# Error Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---792_CONFIG): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 below the `Warning` come.

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---792_CONFIG): 
failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 663
```

Please Help.

After changing permissions I got an error "Class Magento\Review\Model\ReviewFactory does not exist"

Ok, I fixed above error by deleting generation folder and making static content deploy

Comment: var folder should have write permission.

Comment: run commands as sudo

Comment: I have the same problem. I can fix it by running a chmod command, but it reoccurs when I run cache:clean or someting else. I think the real problem is some extension that sets the permissions wrong. But how can we fix that?

Comment: I got the same issue even after assigning permission, the issue keeps appearing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento told you that you don't have permissions to write in /var/cache folder, please check what are the permission of the /var folder.

[Overview of ownership and permissions Magento 2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html)

Answer (score 4):

I tried with `sudo bin/magento setup:di:compile` and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can try changing all permissions by using the following command

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

I know it's not the prettiest solutions, but it worked for me.

Comment: After i run these commands, i am getting the fatal error and not writable error

Answer (score 0):

you have a permission problem

Fix it by using this cmd : `chmod 755 -R var/*`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a bug, I experienced the same after running the cache: clean command as root user.

So by applying for the file permission again, this issue has been fixed. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

So be careful don't clean the cache as root/sudo user

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has recently had this problem.
I fixed this in my staging environment by running the chmod 755 -R var/* command, but make sure you do it to the /var directory and not /var/www/html/var. Hope it makes sense. I am quiet new to Linux so it took a while for me to get my head around.

This is also a very important reard https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html

Answer (score 0):

The below fixed my problem, and magento runs very smooth ever.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;

find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod g+w {} +

find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod g+ws {} +

//Change the ownership to your Magento user
sudo chown -R <Magento user>:<web server group> .

//<web server group> usually will be www-data
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this will fix
chmod 777 -R var/*