# About index Fatal error

Tags: error, magento2.2, index

I have some problem, on my magento

- 2.2.1
- php71
- centos7
- EasyApache 4
- PHPfpm
- suphp
- MYSQL5.6.38

Please help, thank you very much

- chmod 777 vendor
- chmod 777 app/etc
- chmod 777 pub/static
- chmod 777 var
- chmod 777 generated
- chmod 777 var/log/debug.log
- chmod 777 var/cache
- chmod 777 var/composer_home
- chmod 777 var/log
- chmod 777 var/page_cache
- chmod 777 vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file

**update**

> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_STORE_RELATIONS):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_STORE_RELATIONS):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE): failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646
>
> Warning:
>   file_put_contents(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_CONFIG_SCOPES):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 663
>
> Warning:
>   fopen(/home/XXX/public_html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---1e8_MAGE):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied in
>   /home/XXX/public_html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php
>   on line 646 An error has happened during application run. See
>   exception log for details.

Comment: Ensure that that file (`var/log/debug.log`) is created and writable by the web server.

Comment: Give write permission for var folder

Comment: @MattAntley updated , please help

Comment: updated , please help @JeevaChezhiyan

Answer (score 0):

Change the permissions to var/log/ folder.
Run chmod -R 777 var/log/ command from magento root directory.

Comment: yes, i getting new error, please see the post, i updated, please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your root folder,

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; 
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Comment: Try this link too, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141545/error-warning-file-put-contents-var-www-html-var-cache-mage-tags-mage-792-c

Comment: hi i getting new issue now,if you know please help,thank you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/204920/error-in-php-module