# Error in php Module

Tags: php, module, error, magento2.2

I have some problem, on my magento,please help~

- 2.2.0
- php71
- centos7
- EasyApache 4
- PHPfpm
- suphp
- MYSQL5.6.38

An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.

> [07-Dec-2017 12:49:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already
>   loaded in Unknown on line 0 [07-Dec-2017 12:49:25 UTC] PHP Warning: 
>   Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 [07-Dec-2017
>   12:49:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown
>   on line 0 [07-Dec-2017 12:49:25 UTC] PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick'
>   already loaded in Unknown on line 0 [07-Dec-2017 12:49:25 UTC] PHP
>   Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
>
> [root@XX ~]# php -v ea-php-cli Copyright 2017 cPanel, Inc. 
>   Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded PHP 7.1.12 (cli) 
>   (built: Dec  4 2017 16:11:46) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>   with Zend OPcache v7.1.12, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
>
> [root@XX ~]# php -m 
>   Cannot load Zend OPcache - it was already loaded 
>   [PHP Modules] bcmath Core ctype curl date dom filter ftp gd
>   hash iconv imagick intl json libxml mbstring mcrypt mysqli    mysqlnd
>   openssl pcntl pcre PDO pdo_mysql pdo_sqlite Phar posix    readline
>   redis Reflection session SimpleXML soap SPL sqlite3 standard
>   tokenizer wddx xml xmlreader xmlwriter xsl Zend OPcache zip zlib
>
> [Zend Modules] Zend OPcache

Answer (score 0):

The errors indicate that dynamic extensions are being loaded via `.ini` files, even though they are already compiled into the PHP binary.

To fix this problem, you must edit your `php.ini` (or extensions.ini) file and comment-out the extensions that are already compiled-in.

For example, after editing, your `ini` file may look like the lines below:

```
;extension=imagick.so
```

You may also erase those lines instead of commenting them out. Once you have disabled those lines, run `php -v` to see if the warnings go away.

Also, to see which extensions are compiled-in to your PHP binary, run the following command:

`php -m`

Comment: Hello,i already deleted extension=imagick.so in my php.ini, but still have a p roblem. i run php -v >> please see the post

Comment: How did you install the extension? What php version did you use to install it? If you used php 5 and now using php 7, it might be that the file in loaded under a different name, therefore, loaded twice.

Comment: i using EasyApache4 to install the extension. PHP Version 7.1.12.but EasyApache4 have no imagick, so i in php.net to install this extension.

Comment: so how to uninstall  imagick? and then reinstall?thank you