# I'm going crazy with the folder permissions! in magento 2

Tags: magento2, permissions, file-permissions

hello guys in my case when I want to run any command like 'bin/magento setup:upgrade && bin/magento cache:clean && bin/magento cache:flush
' or bin/magento setup:di:upgrade , it always shows met his error :

```
Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/myproject/web/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---a0a_CONFIG): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/myproject/web/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php on line 646
```

> can anyone tell me how to solve this problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

Magento told you that you don't have permissions to write in /var/cache folder, please check what are the permission of the /var folder.

**https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html**

And More refer this link :-

**[Error Warning: file_put_contents(/var/www/html/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---792_CONFIG): failed to open stream: Permission denied](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141545/error-warning-file-put-contents-var-www-html-var-cache-mage-tags-mage-792-c)**

Comment: Hello it's answer is helpful ??

Answer (score 0):

You should run this command:

```
chmod -R 777  var pub generated
```

Please let me know if it works!

Comment: it work , but when a get access to a website after setup:upgrade it tells me , permission denied for generate folder